# Function template specialization with a template class

Tags: c++, function, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [partial specialization of function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215365/partial-specialization-of-function-template)

I can't find anywhere a solution for my problem, because if I search with the keywords I come up with would give me solutions suited for different problems. I understand that this must been asked before, just can't find a solution.

Suppose I have a function template:

```
template<class any> print(any value);
```

I can specialize it like this for let's say a `int`:

```
template<> print<int>(int value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}
```

But now the problem, I want it to work with a vector as well. Since the vector class is a template class it becomes difficult.

Specializing the function like this:

```
template<class any> print<vector<any> >(vector<any> value) {}
```

Will generate the following error (MinGW g++):

```
FILE: error: function template partial specialization 'print<vector<any> >' is not allowed
```

**Note that the function print is just an example.**

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215365/partial-specialization-of-function-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general workaround in which the function-template just delegates the job to class template member functions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct helper {
    static void print(T value) { std::cout << value; }
};
template <typename T> struct helper<std::vector<T>> {
    static void print(std::vector<T> const &value) { }
};

template <typename T>
void print (T const &value) {
    // Just delegate.
    helper<T>::print (value);
}


int main () {
    print (5);
    std::vector<int> v;
    print (v);
}
```

However, if you can come by with simple function overloading (as suggested by ecatmur and Vaughn Cato), do so.

Comment: I confronted alot of problems using the overload eventualy, this works for me thanks!

Comment: Does it has to be specialized in the **same** file? Getting a lot of errors right now..

Comment: It does not have to be, but typically it is better. Spreading specializations over different files that are not guaranteed to be included together, it may give you some pain, especially when you don't have much experience with templates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. By what time the do the templates specializations have to be included? By the time it is used in a defined function, or by the time before the `int main() {...}` is defined?
**Edit:** And why can I specialize function templates in other units and class templates not!?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to specialize function templates.  Use overloading instead

```
void print(int value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}
```

and

```
template<class any>
void print(vector<any> value) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function template partial specialization is not allowed because it would lead to one-definition-rule violations.  You can usually just use an overload:

```
template<class any> print(vector<any> value) {}
```