# Is it possible to use specialize a template with no argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I do this syntax for myself as I think it is more convenience for later.

```
temolate<typename U> struct identity{typedef U type;};
temolate<typename T, typename identity<T>::type value=0> struct my{
    typedef std::vector<T> vec;
    typedef std::array<T,value> arr;
    typedef std::set<T> set;
    // and so forth
};
```

And I use it:

```
int main(){
    my<int>::vec v;   // okay
    my<int,3>::arr a; // okay
    // and so forth
}
```

But I also wish to do this syntax:
(specialize of **my** above)

```
template<??????????>  // what should I do here?
struct my<?????????>{ // or may be here
    typedef int i;
    typedef float f;
    typedef double d;
    // and so forth;
}
```

So that I can do this:

```
int main(){
    my::i a; // for int, what should I do?
    my::f b; // for float,  and
    my::d c; // for double, and
    // AND I ALSI CAN
    my<int>::vec v;    // already I know
    my<int,3>::arr a;  // and know
}
```

**Is it possible?**

---

I have seen here:
[Default template parameter partial specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700558/default-template-parameter-partial-specialization)
before I ask. So I know `my<>::i` is possible.

And I also know how to use **alias** with **using**

I JUST ASK it is possible? Instead of saying **NO** to me, you get me **downvote**

Comment: If I understand it correctly. Sure you can, but you still need to use `my<>::i` etc.

Comment: What's a **done vote** exactly?

Comment: @skypjack, Thank you. I am not a native English,also just learning it, and I also use my tablet.

Answer (score 4):

You can default your `T` to a special type (here `default_type`) and then specialize for it:

```
template<typename U> struct almost_identity{typedef U type;};

class default_type{};

template<> struct almost_identity<default_type>{ typedef int type; };

template<typename T = class default_type, typename almost_identity<T>::type value = 0> struct my{
    typedef std::vector<T> vec;
    typedef std::array<T,value> arr;
    typedef std::set<T> set;
    // and so forth
};

template<>
struct my<default_type, 0>
{
    typedef int i;
    typedef float f;
    typedef double d;
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rbC7YkRDdXna1SuM)

This will allow you to use `my<>::i`.

If you absolutely want `my::i` and `my<int>::vec` to be correct, then as far as I can tell there's no way to accomplish this.

Comment: compiler says: `error: ‘template<class T, typename almost_identity<U>::type value> struct my’ used without template parameters`

Comment: @k-five where did you get that `U` from?

Comment: @k-five you need to use `my` with template brackets like GillBates suggested i.e. `my<>::i`

Comment: @k-five I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without some ugly macros

Comment: @k-five well you could use of some `using` as skypjack suggested :)

Comment: I before asking saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291270/function-template-specialization-with-a-template-class

Comment: @W.F. I don't see how, not when you want to allow both `my::i` and `my<int>::vec` syntaxes

Comment: @krzaq If it is not possible JUST say no, DO NOT gave my a code

Comment: @k-five but this isn't a function template.

Comment: @krzaq you're right it might be hard to get both at least in one namespace

Comment: @krzaq may be you are right I do not know, as I said , I hope to because it is very clear and beauty

Comment: @k-five unfortunately one cannot do type overloads it's syntactic sugar reserved for functions :)

Comment: @k-five I answered the question as asked. I guess you can blame the language barrier. That said, I don't see how this warrants a downvote.

Comment: @krzaq As I get a down vote. my answer simply is `no` but ...!

Comment: @k-five it's not my down vote but in your question you did not clearly state what is your use case and as such it may be less valuable for future OPs that could have similar question as yours. This does not imply lack of usefulness of skypjack's and krzaq's answers...

Comment: @k-five edit your question to make it clearer and I will be first to upvote :)

Comment: @W.F., @ krzaq Of course YOUR code is useful, but not for me since I know to use `alias`. I just say it is `possible`? I never WANT someone explain to me the different syntax. I always search before I ask.

Comment: @k-five when you come down read answers and comments again - no one here is trying to bug you but to help you

Answer (score 1):

You you are willing to accept a sligtly different name, you can use an *using declaration* to do something similar:

```
using myy = my<int>;
```

Then refer to your type as:

```
myy::i
```

Comment: Sorry my friend I can myself using `alias` with `using` but I hope to do this with the same name `my` noting else, If it is not possible JUST say no

Comment: @k-five Well, thus **no**.