# What should I do instead of partial specialization of function templates?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, overloading, partial-specialization

I want to write the following:

```
template <typename S, typename T> void foo() {
    /* code for the general case */
}

template <typename T> void foo<MySType,T>() {
    /* partially specialized code - for any kind of T, but when S is MySType */
}
```

or, in other cases, the following:

```
template <typename S, typename T> void bar(const S& a, const T& b) {
    /* code for the general case */
}

template <typename T> void bar<MySType,T>(const MySType& a, const T& b) {
    /* partially specialized code - for any kind of T, but when S is MySType */
}
```

C++(11) won't let me do this.

Now, I read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215365/partial-specialization-of-function-template); let's assume I buy the explanation of why we don't have partial template specialization (or just assume that that I'm living in reality and actually want to write code). Well, what *do* I do, in stead?

I would really rather not wrap these functions in a class unless that's absolutely my last resort.

Comment: honestly the more I dive into C++11 and C++ in general, the more I think that "template specialization" is an horrible qualification for what is happening. There is no such thing as "template specialization"

Comment: @user2485710: I'm sorry, I don't understand... can you elaborate? Or link to where you've argued this at more length?

Comment: Not only is template specialization a thing, it's a Turing-complete machine. It can drive you mad, though.

Comment: "specializing" means that you are enhancing the properties of something that already exist, what a template signature is able to perform is type inference or type deduction, to create the functions that you need. To specialize things you need at least 1 thing that already exist plus at least 1 properties to enhance/change, I never get why someone would call this "template specialization" when in fact there is just some type inference and type deduction. Someone even calls this "overload" which is something that only happens at runtime.

Comment: @user2485710: Umm, I would think this is specialization since we're treating a special case differently than the general case, that's all.

Comment: @einpoklum this functions don't even exist until the compiler process them, and the compiler doesn't see this as specialization, it just fills the right labels with the right type.

Comment: 2485710, no.  Overload resolution happens at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use a helper class template, where you **can** do partial specialization, and hide it using a wrapper function which doesn't need to be partially specialized itself:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename S, typename T>
struct foo_helper {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "general func" << std::endl;        
    }
};

struct MyType {};

template <typename T>
struct foo_helper <MyType,T> {
    void foo() {   
        std::cout << "partially specialized code - for any kind of T, but when S is MyType" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename S, typename T>
void foo() {
    foo_helper<S, T>().foo();
}

int main () {
    foo<int, int>();
    foo<int, double>();
    foo<MyType, long>();
}
```

This is valid C++98/03 as well.

Comment: Can I somehow automatize/macroize the use of the helper structure?

Answer (score 5):

Overload! Overloading is superior in every way to specialization. Part of overload resolution is picking the most specialized overload. Just declare the "specializations" as overloads and it will work if partial specialization would have.

Avoid explicit template arguments, though. You might use tag dispatching instead.

```
template< typename t >
struct tag {};

template <typename S, typename T> foo( tag<S>, tag<T> ) {
    /* code for the general case */
}

template <typename T> foo( tag<MyType>, tag<T> ) {
    /* partially specialized code - for any kind of T, but when S is MyType */
}
```

Since the tags are empty and passed by value, their contribution to function call overhead may be eliminated by the compiler.

Comment: The OP's example is poorly constructed (missing return types, etc), but brings an interesting twist. Mainly, how do you overload something that has *no parameters*?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: So, if S or T are not represented in parameter types, you suggest adding tag parameters to enable overloading. Would you suggest using these also when S and T do correspond to parameters?

Comment: @einpoklum no worries. It didn't detract for the meaningfulness of the question itself. And tag dispatching isn't necessarily intuitive as a solution if you're engrained in specialization of the class-type variety, so don't think it odd you didn't consider it out of the gate.

Comment: @einpoklum If S and T are deduced from parameters, then the tags will only cause troublesome redundancy — the parameter and tag types would have to match or you get an error. Fortunately there's seldom overlap between real parameters and tags.

Comment: @einpoklum and answering your comment, as soon as you start throwing parameters into the mix you can start using real overloads. [See it live](http://ideone.com/9FA2er), but you likely already knew that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Mind making that into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You might partial specialize a helper structure:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Detail {
    template <typename S, typename T>
    struct Foo {
        static void apply() {
            std::cout << "general case\n";
        }
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct Foo<int, T> {
        static void apply() {
            std::cout << "specialized code\n";
        }
    };
}

template <typename S, typename T>
void foo() {
    Detail::Foo<S, T>::apply();
}

int main()
{
    foo<double, double>();
    foo<int, double>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can this be automated/streamlined somehow, so that I don't have to always explicitly write in the namespace, the structs et cetera?